# magento 2 attribute dropdown default value empty?

Tags: attributes, magento2

Is it possible to create an attribute of dropdown type that is not required and that when creating the product the default value of that attribute is null or empty so that it does not affect in the layered navigation?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is very simple to create attribute of dropdown and have first option empty. While creating attribute under  "Manage Options (Values of Your Attribute)" in admin . Do not select is default radio button for any option.Then by default first option will be blank in dropdown.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help